# How to add a data source to PhpStorm?

Tags: database, phpstorm

[image]

I faced this problem and I am trying to add a database to the program ..
I am working for the first time on it

Comment: The error message tells you what to do.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Please [edit] and post the __error-message as text__. The image is good for context, but the message to copy-paste for research. Just __click on the symbols next to the message__ (paper-sheets to copy, globe to search) :-)

Comment: See workarounds and comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7727 : **1)** In DataSource configuration window go to `Advanced` tab and set `serverTimezone` property to `UTC`. **2)** Or switch DataSource driver to MySQL Connector/J for 5.1 (my version is 5.1.46)